# Famous Last Words (or Escape the Concatenation Camp)

Tags: word, letters

Word War II has been raging for years, and many innocent words have been rounded up into concatenation camps (which is certainly a death sentence). Thus far, you've managed to evade detection but many of your friends have not been so lucky.

Though it likely spells your doom, you've decided to help and have dug a narrow tunnel into one of the camps through which you'll be able to help a small group of words escape. Unfortunately you can barely get a word in edgewise, so they'll have to come through a few letters at a time. The even bigger problem, is that once on the outside the escapees will need to be disguised or they'll be too easily recognised and risk being caught again.

The night of the escape comes, and a small group of words has gathered near the entrance to the tunnel:

> **abstruse, condors, honest, invention, neon, reacted, vague**

Now it's up to you to help them escape and ensure their disguises are good enough to evade detection on the outside.

---

**Rules**:

1. Move words or word fragments from one side of the tunnel to the other until all constituent letters have escaped to the other side
2. Word fragments must always be a contiguous sequence of letters taken from the start or the end of a single existing word
3. Movement can only occur from one side of the tunnel to the other (i.e. you can't rearrange words whilst still on one side), however you can move through the tunnel in either direction
4. Words formed on either side of the tunnel must always be valid dictionary words (see clarifications below), though fragments in transit need not
5. In order to remain disguised, any word that appears at any time on one side of the tunnel, must never appear on the other side in the exact same form (the corollary of which is that a word can't move directly in whole from one side to the other)

---

**A simple, one word example** (with "@" being the tunnel):

> reheated @
>   *reheat* @ *ed*
>   *heat* @ *reed*
>   *he* @ reed, *at*
>   *here* @ *ed*, at
>   *there* @ ed, *a*
>   *re* @ ed, a, *the*
>   @ ed, *are*, the

---

**Clarifications on what constitutes a "word"**:

To be considered a valid word, it must have an entry on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.com), with the following stipulations:

- English words only
- No acronyms and abbreviations (though shortenings that have become common words, such as "ed" are ok, so long as they're listed as such)
- No proper nouns
- Informal words are ok, but regional specific slang is not

---

**Edit (Oct 6)**:

I recognise that retrospectively changing things is a little unfair to existing answers (please don't downvote them), but I wanted to make a few further clarifications as to my intentions of what constitutes a word:

- Use of accented characters isn't allowed ("é" is not the same as "e")
- Just having an entry on dictionary.com doesn't make it a word (eg. every letter of the alphabet has it's own entry, but they aren't words, unless it has additional definition, eg. "I" or "a", similarly chemical symbols aren't words)
- Related/Derived forms of a given word are allowed, even when they don't have a page of their own (eg. "test" has a page, and lists things like "testing" and "testability" under derived forms even though they don't have their own individual entry pages)

That being said the English language is by it's very nature fluid, so while I'm trying to be unambiguous, all these rules are going to be somewhat subjective and I'm happy for people to argue their case for exceptions.

---

***Edit (Oct 27)***:

*I've [posted my reference solution below](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/23568/5208), if anyone is interested. It's marked as accepted since it's currently the "best" solution. Still happy to move the tick if anyone can make improvements...*

---

<sup>**Note**: There's potentially multiple solutions to this problem, so if multiple people get it, I'll award the tick to the person who can arrive at the least number of words on the other side of the tunnel (with the least number of steps taken as a tie-breaker). For reference, my solution results in 6 words.</sup>

Comment: Is a word on the outside allowed to consist of the parts of multiple original words? (example: se from abstru-se + cond from cond-ors = second)

Comment: @TheDarkTruth - Absolutely. They'll have to. As long as everything on both sides are always words.

Comment: Is there room in the tunnel for fragments of two (or more) words to travel concurrently, e.g. the 's' from **condors** and the 'on' from **neon**, forming **son** on the outside?

Comment: @GordonK - Nope. One fragment at a time.

Comment: So if there's a word, say "outside" can it split to "out" and "side" or would "out" be caught on the outside because it's not disguised well enough?

Comment: @Raystafarian - That's fine. Just can't be identical words.

Comment: Wait, where did the previous answer with the word "vagi" go?

Comment: @Hackiisan - I only see one deleted answer, but I don't see the word "vagi"...

Comment: I know it's your puzzle so you can do anything you like, but surely "ed" is not a word?

Comment: Please can you extend the dead line a little?  I haven't had enough of a chance to work on this, but I feel like I might be getting close!

Comment: @DrXorile - Unfortunately you can't change bounty deadlines. I do get a 24hr grace period to award it, so there's still effectively ~48hrs from now. That being said, If you don't make the deadline, I'll hold off posting my solution for another week after that and if you can find a worthy solution I'll still give you the tick and an upvote. If you beat my own solution, I'll throw you an extra bounty too. :)

Comment: More than fair. I can't ask for more than that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For reference, here's the solution I (OP) came up with while constructing this puzzle. I'm marking it as the "accepted" answer because I believe it is currently the best solution. If anyone improves on it, I'll move the tick.

> 0: abstruse, reacted, honest, condors, invention, neon, vague @
>   1: abstruse, *react*, honest, condors, invention, neon, vague @ **ed**
>   2: abstruse, *act*, honest, condors, invention, neon, vague @ **re**ed
>   3: abstruse, act, honest, condors, *invent*, neon, vague @ reed, **ion**
>   4: abstruse, honest, condors, invent, neon, vague @ reed, **act**ion
>   5: abstruse, honest, *condor*, invent, neon, vague @ reed**s**, action
>   6: *use*, honest, condor, invent, neon, vague @ reeds, **abstr**action
>   7: use, honest, condor, invent**s**, neon, vague @ *reed*, abstraction
>   8: use, honest, condor, **re**invents, neon, vague @ *ed*, abstraction
>   9: use, honest, *condo*, reinvents, neon, vague @ **red**, abstraction
>   10: use, honest, *con*, reinvents, neon, vague @ red, abstraction, **do**
>   11: honest, con, reinvents, neon, vague @ red, abstraction, **douse**
>   12: honest, con, *reinvent*, neon, vague @ red, abstraction, douse**s**
>   13: honest, con**do**, reinvent, neon, vague @ red, abstraction, *uses*
>   14: honest, con, reinvent, neon, vague @ red, abstraction, uses, **do**
>   15: honest, con, reinvent, *on*, vague @ red, abstraction, uses, do**ne**
>   16: honest, reinvent, on, vague @ red, abstraction, uses, **con**done
>   17: **abs**, honest, reinvent, on, vague @ red, *traction*, uses, condone
>   18: abs**cond**, honest, reinvent, on, vague @ red, traction, uses, *one*
>   19: abscond, *hone*, reinvent, on, vague @ red, traction, uses, **st**one
>   20: abscond, hone, reinvent, on, vague**r** @ *ed*, traction, uses, stone
>   21: abscond, hone, reinvent, on, *vague* @ ed, traction, **r**uses, stone
>   22: abscond, hone, reinvent, on, vague**st** @ ed, traction, ruses, *one*
>   23: abscond, hone, reinvent**ion**, on, vaguest @ ed, *tract*, ruses, one
>   24: abscond, hone, *reinvent*, on, vaguest @ ed, tract, ruses, one, **ion**
>   25: abscond, hone**r**, reinvent, on, vaguest @ ed, tract, *uses*, one, ion
>   26: abscond, honer, *invent*, on, vaguest @ ed, **re**tract, uses, one, ion
>   27: abscond, honer, *vent*, on, vaguest @ ed, retract, uses, one, ion, **in**
>   28: abscond, honer, vent, on, *guest* @ ed, retract, uses, one, ion, **va**in
>   29: abscond, *hon*, vent, on, guest @ ed, retract, uses, one, ion, vain**er**
>   30: abscond, *ho*, vent, on, guest @ ed, retract, uses, **n**one, ion, vainer
>   31: ho, vent, on, guest @ **abscond**ed, retract, uses, none, ion, vainer
>   32: vent, on, guest @ absconded, retract, **ho**uses, none, ion, vainer
>   33: on, guest @ absconded, retract, houses, none**vent**, ion, vainer
>   34: guest @ absconded, retract, houses, nonevent, **on**ion, vainer
>   35: @ absconded, retract, **guest**houses, nonevent, onion, vainer

Comment: Very good solution!  I have some appreciation for how hard this is!

Answer (score 5):

This was tricky:

> 0 (start): abstruse, condors, honest, invention, neon, reacted, vague, @
> 1: abstruse, condors, honest, invention, neon, *react*, vague, @, **ed**
> 2: abstruse, condors, honest, invention, neon, *re*, vague, @, **act**, ed
> 3: *use*, condors, honest, invention, neon, re, vague, @, **abstr**act, ed
> 4: use, *con*, honest, invention, neon, re, vague, @, abstract, **dors**, ed
> 5: use, con, honest, invention**s**, neon, re, vague, @, abstract, *dor*, ed
> 6: use**r**, con, honest, inventions, neon, re, vague, @, abstract, do, ed
> 7: user, con, honest, *ions*, neon, re, vague, @, abstract, **invent**, do, ed
> 8: *er*, con, honest, ions, neon, re, vague, @, abstract, invent, do, **us**ed
> 9: er, con**vent**, honest, ions, neon, re, vague, @, abstract, *in*, do, used
> 10: er, *vent*, honest, ions, neon, re, vague, @, abstract, in, **con**do, used
> 11: er, vent, honest, ions, neon, vague, @, abstract, **re**in, condo, used
> 12: er, honest, ions, neon, vague, @, abstract, rein**vent**, condo, used
> 13: er, *ho*, ions, neon, vague, @, abstract, reinvent, condo, used, **nest**
> 14: er, ions, neon, vague, @, abstract, reinvent, condo, **ho**used, nest
> 15: er, neon, vague, @, abstract, reinvent**ions**, condo, housed, nest
> 16: neon, vague, @, abstract**er**, reinventions, condo, housed, nest
> 17: neon, vague**st**, @, abstracter, reinventions, condo, housed, *ne*
> 18: neon, *guest*, @, abstracter, reinventions, condo, housed, **va**ne
> 19: *on*, guest, @, abstracter, reinventions, condo**ne**, housed, vane
> 20: on**e**, guest, @, abstracter, reinventions, condone, housed, *van*
> 21: **d**one, guest, @, abstracter, reinventions, condone, *house*, van
> 22: done, @, abstracter, reinventions, condone, **guest**house, van
> 23: *e*, @, abstracter, reinventions, condone, guesthouse, van, **don**
> 24: e**s**, @, abstracter, *reinvention*, condone, guesthouse, van, don
> 25 (finish): @, abstracter, reinvention, condone, guesthouse, van**es**, don

Comment: I'm not sure about the words "e", "es", "ne".

Comment: While I admit it's likely necessary to bend the acceptability of what constitutes a word a little to solve this, I'm inclined to agree with @BenFrankel here and therefore not mark this as the solution. I think "e" being considered a word is a bit of a stretch given that it's listed simply as a letter of the alphabet, and both "Es" & "Ne" are abbreviations in my book. That being said, +1 for a solid attempt.

Answer (score 4):

I've been working on this for days now (see original date and dozens of edits). I'm so close.

1. abstruse, condors, honest, invention, neon, **acted**, vague @ **re**
2. abstruse, condors, **hone**, invention, neon, acted, vague @ re**st**
3. abstruse, condors, hone, invention, neon, acted, vague**st** @ **re**
4. abstruse, condors, hone, **ion**, neon, acted, vaguest @ re, **invent**
5. abstruse, condors, hone, ion, neon, acted, vaguest, **vent** @ re, **in**
6. abstruse, condors, hone, ion, neon, acted, **guest**, vent @ re, **va**in
7. abstruse, condors, hone, ion, neon, **ed**, guest, vent @ re, vain, **act**
8. **use**, condors, hone, ion, neon, ed, guest, vent @ re, vain, **abstr**act
9. condors, hone, ion, neon, ed, guest, vent @ re**use**, vain, abstract
10. **condor**, hone, ion, neon, ed, guest, vent @ reuse**s**, vain, abstract
11. condor, hone, ion, neon, ed, guest, vent, **tract** @ reuses, vain, **abs**
12. **dor** <sup>[src](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dor?s=t)</sup>, hone, ion, neon, ed, guest, vent, tract @ reuses, vain, abs, con
13. dor, hone, ion, neon, ed, guest, tract @ reuses, vain, abs, con**vent**
14. **do**, hone, ion, neon, ed, guest, tract @ reuses, vain **r**abs <sup>[src](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rab?s=ts)</sup>, convent
15. do, hone, ion, neon, **re**ed, guest, tract @ **uses**, vain, rabs, convent
16. do, hone, ion, neon, **ed**, guest, tract @ uses, vain, rabs, convent, **re**
17. hone, ion, neon, ed, guest, tract @ uses, vain, rabs, convent, re**do**
18. **ho**, ion, neon, ed, guest, tract @ uses, vain, rabs, convent, redo**ne**
19. ion, neon, ed, guest, tract @ **ho**uses, vain, rabs, convent, redone
20. ion, neon, ed, tract @ **guest**houses, vain, rabs, convent, redone
21. ion, neon, **r**ed, tract @ guesthouses, vain, **abs**, convent, redone
22. ion, neon, red**abs**, tract @ guesthouses, vain, convent, redone
23. ion, neon, **dabs**, tract @ guesthouses, vain, convent, redone, **re**
24. ion, neon, dabs @ guesthouses, vain, convent, redone, re**tract**
25. neon, dabs @ guesthouses, vain, convent, redone, retract**ion**
26. neon, **re**dabs @ guesthouses, vain, convent, redone, **traction**
27. neon, **red** @ guesthouses, vain, convent, redone, traction, **abs**
28. neon, red, **vent** @ guesthouses, vain, **con**, redone, traction, abs
29. neon, **ed**, vent @ guesthouses, vain, con, redone, traction, **r**abs
30. neon, **re**ed, vent @ guesthouses, vain, con, **done**, traction, rabs
31. neon, **ed**, vent @ guesthouses, vain, con, done, **re**traction, rabs
32. neon, ed, vent, **ion** @ guesthouses, vain, con, done **retract**, rabs
33. neon, ed, vent, **i** @ guesthouses, vain, con, done, retract, rabs, **on**
34. **neo**, ed, vent, i @ guesthouses, vain, cont, done, retract, rabs, **non**
35. ed, vent, I @ guesthouses, vain, **neo**con, done, retract, rabs, non
36. ed, vent, i**va** <sup>[src](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/iva?s=t)</sup> @ guesthouses, **in**, neocon, done, retract, rabs, non
37. ed, iva @ guesthouses, in**vent**, neocon, done, retract, rabs, non
38. ed, **a** @ guesthouses, invent, neocon, done, retract, rabs, non, **IV** <sup>[src](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/iv?s=t)</sup>
39. ed @ guesthouses, invent, neocon, done, retract, rabs, **a**non, IV
40. @ guesthouses, invent**ed**, neocon, done, retract, rabs, anon, IV

---

If **neo** isn't counted, this is where I'm at

34. **eon**, ed, vent, i @ guesthouses, vain, cont, done, retract, rabs, **non**
35. eon, ed, vent, i**va** <sup>[src](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/iva?s=t)</sup> @ guesthouses, **in**, con, done, retract, rabs, non
36. eon, ed, iva @ guesthouses, in**vent**, con, done, retract, rabs, non
37. eon, ed, **IV** <sup>[src](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/iv?s=t)</sup> @ guesthouses, invent, con, done, retract, rabs, non, **a**
38. ed, IV @ guesthouses, invent, con, done, retract, rabs, non, a**eon**
39. IV @ guesthouses, invent**ed**, con, done, retract, rabs, non, aeon

Just gotta figure out how to get that *V* over there and then make **icon**

Comment: I think that final step is not allowed since ague has been on both sides. otherwise very nice attempt i think

Comment: I could be wrong but maybe the OP can clarify this, although I think that "any word that appears at any time on one side of the tunnel, must never appear on the other side in the exact same form" is pretty clear

Comment: "Ruse" should be "use".

Comment: And *con* and *on* it seems.

Comment: Rule 3 says that you can't do that.

Comment: +1 for your efforts. It's not an easy task. ...I'm putting up a bounty, so you still have a chance to find a solution if you're not too frustrated by it. :)

Comment: Steps 28 and 31 and 36 are fickle. 35-36, a whole word vanishes? ('done')

Comment: @Alconja This *should* work, the only questionable word is **neo** (#34)

Answer (score 4):

> 0: abstruse, condors, honest, invention, neon, reacted, vague @
>  1: abstruse, condors, honest, invention, neon, *react*, vague @ **ed**
>  2: abstruse, condors, honest, invention, neon, *re*, vague @ ed, **act**
>  3: *use*, condors, honest, invention, neon, re, vague @ ed, **abstr**act
>  4: use, *dors*, honest, invention, neon, re, vague @ ed, abstract, **con**
>  5: use, *dor*, honest, invention, neon, re, vague @ ed, abstract**s**, con
>  6: use, dor, honest, *ion*, neon, re, vague @ ed, abstracts, con, **invent**
>  7: use, dor, honest, *on*, neon, re, vague @ ed, abstracts, con, invent, **i**
>  8: use, dor, honest, *o*, neon, re, vague @ ed, abstracts, con, invent, i**n**
>  9: use, *do*, honest, o, neon, re, vague @ ed, abstracts, con, invent, **r**in
>  10: use**r**, do, honest, o, neon, re, vague @ ed, abstracts, con, invent, *in*
>  11: *us*, do, honest, o, neon, re, vague @ ed, abstracts, con, invent, in, **er**
>  12: do, honest, o, neon, re, vague @ **us**ed, abstracts, con, invent, in, er
>  13: do, *hone*, o, neon, re, vague @ used, abstracts, con, invent, in, er**st**
>  14: do, hone, o, neon, re, vague**st** @ used, abstracts, con, invent, in, *er*
>  15: hone, o, neon, re, vaguest @ used, abstracts, con**do**, invent, in, er
>  16: *ho*, o, neon, re, vaguest @ used, abstracts, condo**ne**, invent, in, er
>  17: ho, o**ne**, neon, re, vaguest @ used, abstracts, *condo*, invent, in, er
>  18: ho, one, neon, re**do**, vaguest @ used, abstracts, *con*, invent, in, er
>  19: ho, one, neon, *o*, vaguest @ used, abstracts, con, invent, in, er**red**
>  20: ho**ed**, one, neon, o, vaguest @ used, abstracts, con, invent, in, *err*
>  21: hoed, one**r**, neon, o, vaguest @ used, abstracts, con, invent, in, *er*
>  22: hoed, oner, neon, o, *guest* @ used, abstracts, con, invent, **va**in, er
>  23: hoed, oner, neon, o**va**, guest @ used, abstracts, con, invent, *in*, er
>  24: hoed, oner, neon, *a*, guest @ used, abstracts, con, invent, in, **ov**er
>  25: hoed, oner, *eon*, a, guest @ used, abstracts, con, invent, in**n**, over
>  26: hoed, oner, eon, a**n**, guest @ used, abstracts, con, invent, *in*, over
>  27: hoed, oner, *on*, an, guest @ used, abstracts, con**e**, invent, in, over
>  28: hoed, oner, on, an**e**, guest @ used, abstracts, *con*, invent, in, over
>  29: hoed, oner, on, guest @ used, abstracts, con, invent, in**ane**, over
>  30: *ho*, oner, on, guest @ used, abstracts, con**ed**, invent, inane, over
>  31: oner, on, guest @ **ho**used, abstracts, coned, invent, inane, over
>  32: oner, **d**on, guest @ housed, abstracts, *cone*, invent, inane, over
>  33: oner, don**e**, guest @ housed, abstracts, *con*, invent, inane, over
>  34: oner, guest @ housed, abstracts, con, invent, inane, over**done**
>  35: *one*, guest @ housed, abstracts, con, invent, inane**r**, overdone
>  36: **d**one, guest @ *house*, abstracts, con, invent, inaner, overdone
>  37: guest @ house, abstracts, con**done**, invent, inaner, overdone
>  38: @ **guest**house, abstracts, condone, invent, inaner, overdone

Formatting and some word ideas from @GordonK - thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure about "neer". The dictionary I'm using shows "neer" as "ne'er", a contraction of "never". However, I don't think I would count "shouldnt" without the apostrophe as a word, for instance.

Comment: @BenFrankel Huh. Totally missed that. Well, back to the notepad and dictionary for me then.

Comment: Definitely a +1, but "ne'er" and "donnée" (note the é) are probably stretching a little. That being said, I'm not going to claim it's outright wrong, lest people nitpick my own solution. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Some back and forth on a few words. I'm not sure about "ane"; Scrabble likes it.

Comment: Rule 5 states that a word cannot appear on both sides of the tunnel, but you've got **use** on the left in 3, 4, 5 and on the right in 16-34.

Comment: @GordonK You're right. I think I can resolve that easily (later). If not, I'll revert to my first answer as “maybe" words are better than absolutely broken rules.

Comment: Just noticed your update (obviously OP only gets notified on new posts, not edits). Looks pretty good. Though *ane* & *oner* are straying into "regional specific slang" a bit. I'm going to put up a bounty to see if anyone can do better, but if there's no other contenders, this will take the prize (I'll post my solution afterwards, for reference).

Comment: @Alconja Thanks! I agree with “ane" and “oner" so I look forward to better answers.

Comment: As promised, the bounty has expired and there's no other improved answers, so you take the prize. Congrats. I'm holding off actually accepting the answer though, as @DrXorile has said he's still working on a solution too. We'll see what happens over the next few days...

Comment: I appreciate the extra time!  I hope I can make it worthwhile!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding "reheated", it seems that you can do it:

> ['reheated'] / []
>   ['re'] / ['heated']
>   ['reed'] / ['heat']
>   ['re'] / ['heat', 'ed']
>   [] / ['reheat', 'ed']

I know it was just an example, but I wanted to confirm that I had a correct understanding of how it worked.  This assumes that you're allowed "ed", which is marginal, IMHO!

To do it without "ed", you could do it like this:

> ['reheated']  /  []
>    ['heated']  /  ['re']
>    ['heat']  /  ['reed']
>    ['at']  /  ['reed', 'he']
>    ['a']  /  ['treed', 'he']
>    ['ad']  /  ['tree', 'he']
>    []  /  ['tree', 'head']

Still working on the full puzzle...

---

Edit:

> 1 ['abstruse', 'condors', 'honest', 'invention', 'neon', 'reacted', 'vague'] @ []
>   2 ['abstruse', 'condors', 'honest', 'invention', 'neon', 'react', 'vague'] @ ['**ed**']
>   3 ['abstruse', 'condors', 'honest', 'invention', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', '**act**']
>   4 ['use', 'condors', 'honest', 'invention', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', '**abstr**act']
>   5 ['use', 'condors', 'honest', 'invent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstract**ion**']
>   6 ['use', 'condors', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstraction', '**in**']
>   7 ['use', 'condor', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstraction**s**', 'in']
>   8 ['use', 'condo', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstractions', '**r**in']
>   9 ['use**r**', 'condo', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstractions', 'in']
>   10 ['us', 'condo', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstractions', 'in', '**er**']
>   11 ['us', 'condo', 'ho', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstractions', 'in', 'er**nest**']
>   12 ['condo', 'ho', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['**us**ed', 'abstractions', 'in', 'ernest']
>   13 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['**ho**used', 'abstractions', 'in', 'ernest']
>   14 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 're**d**', 'vague'] @ ['house', 'abstractions', 'in', 'ernest']
>   15 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 'red', 'vague**st**'] @ ['house', 'abstractions', 'in', 'erne']
>   16 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 'red', 'guest'] @ ['house', 'abstractions', '**va**in', 'erne']
>   17 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 'red'] @ ['**guest**house', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'erne']
>   18 ['con', 'vent', 'neon', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'erne', '**do**']
>   19 ['con**tractions**', 'vent', 'neon', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abs', 'vain', 'erne', 'do']
>   20 ['contractions', 'vent', 'on', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abs', 'vain', 'erne', 'do**ne**']
>   21 ['con', 'vent', 'on', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abs', 'vain', 'erne', 'done', '**tractions**']
>   22 ['vent', 'on', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abs', 'vain', 'erne', '**con**done', 'tractions']
>   23 ['vent', 'o', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', '**n**abs', 'vain', 'erne', 'condone', 'tractions']
>   24 ['vent', 'o', 're'] @ ['guesthouse', 'nabs', 'vain', 'erne', 'condone**d**', 'tractions']
>   25 ['vent', 'o'] @ ['guesthouse', 'nabs', 'vain', 'erne', 'condoned', '**re**tractions']
>   26 ['vent', 'o**ne**'] @ ['guesthouse', 'nabs', 'vain', 'er', 'condoned', 'retractions']
>   27 ['one'] @ ['guesthouse', 'nabs', 'vain', '**vent**er', 'condoned', 'retractions']
>   28 ['one**s**'] @ ['guesthouse', 'nab', 'vain', 'venter', 'condoned', 'retractions']
>   29 ['**b**ones'] @ ['guesthouse', 'na', 'vain', 'venter', 'condoned', 'retractions']
>   30 ['bone'] @ ['guesthouse', 'na', 'vain', 'venter**s**', 'condoned', 'retractions']
>   31 ['bone**d**'] @ ['guesthouse', 'na', 'vain', 'venters', 'condone', 'retractions']
>   32 ['bon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'na', 'vain', 'venters', 'condone', 'retractions', '**ed**']
>   33 ['on'] @ ['guesthouse', 'na', 'vain', 'venters', 'condone', 'retractions', '**b**ed']
>   34 ['**n**on'] @ ['guesthouse', 'a', 'vain', 'venters', 'condone', 'retractions', 'bed']
>   35 [] @ ['guesthouse', 'a**non**', 'vain', 'venters', 'condone', 'retractions', 'bed']

Or, going for fewer steps (edit - down to 30 steps):

> 1 ['abstruse', 'condors', 'honest', 'invention', 'neon', 'reacted', 'vague'] @ []
>   2 ['abstruse', 'condors', 'honest', 'invention', 'neon', 'react', 'vague'] @ ['**ed**']
>   3 ['abstruse', 'condors', 'honest', 'invention', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', '**act**']
>   4 ['use', 'condors', 'honest', 'invention', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', '**abstr**act']
>   5 ['use', 'condors', 'honest', 'invent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstract**ion**']
>   6 ['use', 'condors', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstraction', '**in**']
>   7 ['use', 'condor', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstraction**s**', 'in']
>   8 ['use', 'condo', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstractions', '**r**in']
>   9 ['use**r**', 'condo', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstractions', 'in']
>   10 ['us', 'condo', 'honest', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstractions', 'in', '**er**']
>   11 ['us', 'condo', 'ho', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['ed', 'abstractions', 'in', 'er**nest**']
>   12 ['condo', 'ho', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['**us**ed', 'abstractions', 'in', 'ernest']
>   13 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 're', 'vague'] @ ['**ho**used', 'abstractions', 'in', 'ernest']
>   14 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 're**d**', 'vague'] @ ['house', 'abstractions', 'in', 'ernest']
>   15 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 'red', 'vague**st**'] @ ['house', 'abstractions', 'in', 'erne']
>   16 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 'red', 'guest'] @ ['house', 'abstractions', '**va**in', 'erne']
>   17 ['condo', 'vent', 'neon', 'red'] @ ['**guest**house', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'erne']
>   18 ['condo**ne**', 'vent', 'neon', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'er']
>   19 ['con', 'vent', 'neon', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'er', '**done**']
>   20 ['con**e**', 'vent', 'neon', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'er', 'don']
>   21 ['cone**d**', 'vent', 'neon', 'red'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'er', 'on']
>   22 ['coned', 'vent', 'neon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'er**red**', 'on']
>   23 ['con', 'vent', 'neon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'erred', 'on', '**ed**']
>   24 ['con', 'neon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'erred', 'on', '**vent**ed']
>   25 ['con', 'eon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'erred', '**n**on', 'vented']
>   26 ['con**ed**', 'eon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'err', 'non', 'vented']
>   27 ['con', 'eon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'err', 'non', 'vented', '**ed**']
>   28 ['eon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'err', 'non', '**con**vented', 'ed']
>   29 ['**n**eon'] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'err', 'on', 'convented', 'ed']
>   30 [] @ ['guesthouse', 'abstractions', 'vain', 'err', 'on', 'convented', '**neon**ed']

Comment: Excellent alternative examples - both would be considered better solutions than mine because they arrived at fewer words (and in fewer steps to boot). As for "marginal" words, it's a tricky one because it starts getting subjective. I don't have a huge issue with "ed", for example in "special ed" and such, but other words I cringe at that some people probably consider fine. For reference the words I consider the "worst" in my solution (but still follow the rules) are probably "[hon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hon?s=t)" & "[honer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/honer?s=t)".

Comment: And, yes, I use "ed" in my actual solution too.

Comment: What about longest solution.  I have one that won't fit in the answer because there's a 30,000 character limit...!

Comment: It gets tricky because of the restriction on not using a word on the other side!

Comment: 30,000+ characters is impressive in its own right. :D I'm surprised there's enough unique word fragments to stretch it out that far (without repetition). And yes, the words on one side only is definitely the heart of the challenge.

Comment: A comment on neoned.  It's in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/neoned), as well as in several scrabble dictionaries.  Neon is in dictionary.com, but not as a verb.  I could get around it fairly easily if "donne" is allowed (which is a proper name, but is in dictionary.com)

Comment: I think "neoned" and "reinventor" both bend the same rule (i.e. technically aren't on dictionary.com, also, to a lesser extent "ors"), but aren't any worse than what other people are doing (eg. Mythi's solution uses "ane" and "oner", which are also rule bending - and arguably worse). That being said, as I commented on Gordon K's answer, I don't think "ne" is really a word.

Comment: Mmm. Missed that comment. I'll think a bit more.

Comment: Also, just noticed "inst", which I think falls into the abbreviations camp.

Comment: Just saw your latest edit, but unfortunately in both it looks like you're duplicating the "st" at step 4. There's also still some IMHO borderline words like "cont" (abbreviation), "non" (prefix/latin), "dorsi" (prefix), but that's less of an issue.

Comment: Oh, wow.  That's a shocker!  This puzzle has proven problematic!  I do love the concept.

Comment: Okay, I've tried some more...

Comment: non is used in "persona non grata", which is a reasonably common expression in English now

Comment: Nice work. I think it's now within the (somewhat stretched) bounds of the rules. Hope it was more fun than frustration. :) Also, if you're interested, I've now posted my own solution.