# I never knew my words could speak!

Tags: word, wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle

<sup><sup>This is an entry to the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #25](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5759/fortnightly-topic-challenge-25-wordplay): [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay).</sup></sup>

---

<sup>*"These words! – they come falling free; / speech: daft here, deft there..."* — [Emrakul](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40424/a-deeper-phrase-of-the-linking-tongue-a-quest-through-the-mind-of-a-respected)</sup>

You know, I've kept some words. Words that work for me. No no, they aren't really my slaves; more like, my pets. They never said they don't like my job or anything; besides, they can't actually do much except what they're told to. They do all sorts of chores for me: like, say, *recording* a *dispute* in the *past*, or *cleaning* my room. They can even *lie* to my *amazing* old *relative* (he's is *one who won't believe*), and *scold* him.

So today morning, as usual, I went to their cage...er, room to take them out and sort out their duties. What I saw there totally blew my mind. I never knew that my pet words could speak! For themselves!

Here's what they seemed to be saying:

> Did G contain H? <sub>L</sub>
>   C's got hold of T, and happens to be E. <sub>R</sub>
>   D equals at least one of C and itself. <sub>C</sub>
>   Regarding N: does G contain H? <sub>L</sub>
>   M stays indoors because of itself. <sub>C</sub>
>   G, P, R – they all happen to be NT. <sub>C</sub>
>   Inside G, L is the same as T. <sub>L</sub>
>   When placed near H, E becomes T. <sub>L</sub>
>   H equals at least one of T and Y. <sub>R</sub>

Now, of course, there are people who "talk" to their pets; frankly speaking, I'm not among them. I didn't even know that my pet words could speak! Seriously, I'm very confused right now.

Just what do these words want to say?

Comment: **Note**: the opening quote from Emrakul is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I feel like this may have occurred in the same universe as [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22812/famous-last-words-or-escape-the-concatenation-camp) (disclaimer: link is to a puzzle of mine)...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The first thing to note is ...

> ... that there are some words in italics in the text above the quote: *recording — dispute — past — cleaning — lie — amazing — relative — one who won't believe — scold*
>
>  These are the definitions for the clues that are given in the quote. These clues must be reworded so that they spell single-word answers. For example, "G contains S" could be rewritten as "S in G" and give the answer SING.

Did G contain H?

> WASHING — cleaning; was H in G?

C's got hold of T, and happens to be E.

> CHASTISE — scold; C has T, is E

D equals at least one of C and itself.

> DISCORD — dispute; D is C or D

Regarding N: does G contain H?

> ASTONISHING — amazing; as to N: Is H in G?

M stays indoors because of itself.

> MISINFORM — lie; M is in for M

G, P, R - they all happen to be NT.

> GRANDPARENT — relative; G, R and P are NT.

Inside G, L is the same as T.

> LISTING — recording; L is T in G.

When placed near H, E becomes T.

> ATHEIST — one who won't believe; At H, E is T.

H equals at least one of T and Y.

> HISTORY — past; H is T or Y.

The subscript letters ...

> ... indicate one of three possible positions: L (left), C (centre) and R (right). When we take the letters from the answers at these positions, we get:
>
>  leftmost letter of WASHING → W
>  rightmost letter of CHASTISE → E
>  central letter of DISCORD → C
>  leftmost letter of ASTONISHING → A
>  central letter of MISINFORM → N
>  central letter of GRANDPARENT → P
>  leftmost letter of LISTING → L
>  leftmost letter of ATHEIST → A
>  rightmost letter of HISTORY → Y

The words want to say:

> **We can play.**

Comment: Woah, that's brilliant!

Comment: @Ankoganit: I don't mind at all. That was a superb puzzle.

Comment: I spent tons of time trying to find a place for HEisT somewhere >_<